# How do I match and replace a domain name without http?

Tags: php, regex

I would like to search in a string and if a domain is found, remove it and be left with what remains. None of these domains will be preceded with http or https.

Example string that I want to remove:

```
domain.com or
domain.something.us
domain.something.uk
```

I thought if I used a wildcard that it would work but I'm not doing something right.

```
$str = preg_replace( '/(?\.net|?\.org|?\.edu|?\.com)/', '', $str );
```

EDIT:

So, all strings generally start with this:

domain.com - some really long string here.....

What I want to do is to just remove everything before the `-`. Sometimes though, a user may have forgotten to add the `domain -`. In that case, it needs to just return the rest of the string.

The output would be:

domain.com - Something long here.

Should be converted to:

Something long here.

Comment: What if the domain is _co.uk_ ?

Comment: Exactly... I need to match that as well.

Comment: Basically, any and all domains. Subdomains would also need to be matched.

Comment: What would be the ouput for `http://example.domain.com/foo?bar`? Can you add a few examples?

Comment: Sure.. I'll post up top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following regular expression with `im` modifiers:

```
^((?:[a-z0-9-]+\.)*[a-z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-z]+){1,2}\s*-)\s*
```

It would match:

- All domain domain names
- Any number of sub-domains
- Multi-level TLDs like `.co.uk`, `.co.in` (only upto two levels)

Note that it would match a lot of invalid domain names as well. But I guess it shouldn't matter if you're just going to remove *all* the domain names from a given piece of text.

[**Regex101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/qG8uL0)

Comment: Yes, Amal, that does seem to work. I looked all over the net for something that would do this. Thank you.

Comment: Really? This requires the domain to be at the start of the string.

Comment: @ohaal: Yes. That's what the OP wanted: "*So, all strings generally start with this:*".

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed ohaal

Comment: Thank you Amal.. I've already plugged it into my script and it seems to be matching everything so far. I really have to learn regex, it's like magic!

Comment: @NaN: Indeed. It *is* magic. If you're just starting out, I recommend you [this interactive tutorial](http://regexone.com/). And when in doubt, use this site as a reference: http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: Let me ask you something.. How long would it take me to be able to become proficient with regex? To me, it looks like another language.

Comment: @NaN: I don't know, to be honest. You can never finish learning. It's just a continuous process! But, to cover the basics, it shouldn't take more than a week.

Comment: That's great. Also, I went to the interactive tutorial and it's fantastic! Thank you for providing that! That's where I'll be starting out

Comment: @AmalMurali, I just wanted to thank you again for the link to that tut. I'm rocking away on regex now. Thank you again!

Comment: @NaN: Good luck! If you want a good book, you can check out Jeffrey Friedl's "Mastering Regular Expressions". It's awesome!

Comment: @AmalMurali, Thanks for the heads up on the book, Amal. I will order it tonight!